# Type mapping MySQL type text to Java Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, text, mapping

What is the correct mapping type from MySQL data type `text` to Java using Hibernate?

```
@Column(name = "STACKTRACE", length = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
public String getStacktrace() {
    return this.stacktrace;
}
```

Comment: Integer.MAX_VALUE?  Really?  For every stack trace?  I'd recommend something more reasonable that's CLOB-sized.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Column(name = "STACKTRACE")
@Type(type="text")
```

Comment: Dear Maurice, I tried the above but I am getting error. your help will be very appreciable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094410/hibernate-abstractmethoderror-setcharacterstreamiljava-io-readerjv?noredirect=1#comment39048566_25094410

Comment: Why not to use ``@Lob`` (although it should generate ``LONGTEXT``) type?

Comment: `@Type(type="text")` generates `longtext` column for me. How to generate `text` column from Hibernate mapping?

Answer (score 20):

I think this solves the problem

```
@Column(length = 65535,columnDefinition="Text")
```

Answer (score 8):

The reverse engineering Hibernate Tools, makes from MySql Type text:

```
@Column(name = "COLUMNNAME", length = 65535)
```

Comment: Indeed. If you look at the `MySqlDialect`, you'll see that it uses the length to derive the type.

Comment: I think thats the better solution if you use JPA.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, I had to annotate like below:

```
@Column(name="LONG_DESCRIPTION" , length = 65535, columnDefinition="TEXT")
@Type(type="text")'
```